# svgwrite - How to enable write/add other objects as layers of an existing .svg file

Tags: python, svg

I have an svg file and I want to insert other svg object inside this existent.

```
import svgwrite

dwg = svgwrite.Drawing('model.svg')
square = dwg.add(dwg.rect(20,20),(80,80), fill='blue'))
dwg.save()
```

it returns a new file with this shape ignoring my previous file.
How could I write this?

Thank's

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found a module to do that

```
import svgutils.transform as st

template = st.fromfile('template.svg')
second_svg = st.fromfile('second.svg')
template.append(second_svg)
template.save('merged.svg')
```

I hope that works for you too.

Answer (score 3):

The `svgwrite` library doesn't support this -- its purpose is to create new SVG files, not work with existing ones. Looking at the [source for the `Drawing` class](https://bitbucket.org/mozman/svgwrite/src/7e90e13bea1c3bcbd4140bd64cf6b7b4d0b98087/svgwrite/drawing.py?at=default), you can see that when you save your drawing, it opens the file for writing and truncates; anything that was previously in that file is lost as a result:

```
def save(self):
    """ Write the XML string to **filename**. """
    fileobj = io.open(self.filename, mode='w', encoding='utf-8')
    self.write(fileobj)
    fileobj.close()
```