# How can I stack two SVG images on top of each other in Python?

Tags: python, image, svg

I am making an app that combines a couple of images. 
The app should stack the images on top of each other.
At first I was using PNG and by using PIL it was easy, It was just:

```
first_layer_image.paste(second_layer_image, (0,0), second_layer_image)
```

How can one do the same using SVG?
For example, here are just 2 out of a couple of SVG images I would like to stack on top of each other.

```
First layer image:

<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4000 4000">
<defs>
    <style>.cls-1{fill:#755841;}.cls-2{fill:#f7c394;}.cls-3{fill:#9b7657;}.cls-4{fill:#7f6145;}.cls-5{fill:#ffc9a1;}.cls-6{fill:#ffcd98;}.cls-7{fill:#3d0c0c;}.cls-8{fill:#fff;}.cls-9{fill:#313cc4;}</style>
</defs>
<title>expanded</title>
<g id="expanded">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M1685.94,3103.49a46.66,46.66,0,0,1-46.27-41.15c-7.68-64.58,15.14-139.41,64.25-210.71,43-62.41,102.73-116.13,159.81-143.72a46.66,46.66,0,1,1,40.6,84c-42.51,20.54-89.86,63.7-123.56,112.64-35.71,51.83-53.36,105.32-48.44,146.75a46.65,46.65,0,0,1-40.82,51.84A47.68,47.68,0,0,1,1685.94,3103.49Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M1698.65,3195a54.69,54.69,0,0,1-19.13-3.46c-16.08-6-29-18.39-38.52-36.88a116,116,0,0,1-11.55-36.67c-4.12-30.82,6.37-57.71,28.78-73.76a54.89,54.89,0,0,1,83.92,62.36,54.91,54.91,0,0,1-43.5,88.41Z" />
    <path class="cls-3" d="M2254,3205.38a158.15,158.15,0,0,1-22.69-1.75c-39-5.71-88.52-24.82-151.33-58.42a18.93,18.93,0,1,1,17.86-33.39c129.79,69.42,172.74,59.15,186.78,46.84,10.58-9.26,9.64-25.54,6.89-55.92-3.21-35.45-7.19-79.56,15.19-130.25,17-38.39,46.73-75,81.7-100.39,40.59-29.51,83.81-41.73,125-35.36,26.53,4.1,53.15,16,74.94,33.57,25,20.14,41.51,45.85,47.69,74.35,5.06,23.34,3.71,51.06-3.62,74.15-9.4,29.64-28.13,50.84-52.75,59.68a78.83,78.83,0,0,1-26.81,4.62c-37.89,0-69.36-25.67-73.53-29.22a18.94,18.94,0,0,1,24.56-28.84c.33.28,33.72,28.3,63,17.8,17-6.1,25.39-22.67,29.45-35.49,5.33-16.81,6.37-37.76,2.7-54.68-5.46-25.19-21.73-42.65-34.42-52.86-16.45-13.25-37.22-22.6-57-25.65-67.11-10.39-138.54,50.89-166.24,113.62-18.43,41.73-15.08,78.81-12.12,111.54,3,33.64,5.92,65.43-19.65,87.82C2295.74,3199.28,2277.1,3205.38,2254,3205.38Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M1877.5,3396.06c-.93,0-1.85,0-2.79,0a68.61,68.61,0,0,1-65.82-71.3c3.54-88.69,25.64-150.48,41.77-195.59,4.87-13.62,9.07-25.38,12.13-35.94a68.61,68.61,0,1,1,131.83,38.09c-4.24,14.66-9.34,28.94-14.75,44.05-14.6,40.85-31.16,87.15-33.86,154.87A68.61,68.61,0,0,1,1877.5,3396.06Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M1761.27,3431A54.9,54.9,0,0,1,1739,3325.93c71.38-31.61,167.74-20.26,211.71-5.67a54.89,54.89,0,1,1-34.57,104.2c-26.37-8.75-93.26-15.61-132.68,1.85A54.74,54.74,0,0,1,1761.27,3431Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M2126.63,3397.47a68.62,68.62,0,0,1-68.44-64.68c-3.88-67.66-21.24-113.66-36.56-154.25-5.67-15-11-29.21-15.51-43.79a68.61,68.61,0,1,1,131.15-40.38c3.23,10.5,7.64,22.19,12.75,35.72,16.92,44.82,40.09,106.22,45.18,194.83a68.63,68.63,0,0,1-64.57,72.44C2129.29,3397.43,2128,3397.47,2126.63,3397.47Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2243.71,3430.39a54.73,54.73,0,0,1-21.32-4.33c-39.72-16.77-106.49-8.74-132.7.47A54.89,54.89,0,0,1,2053.31,3323c43.71-15.35,139.86-28.39,211.78,2a54.9,54.9,0,0,1-21.38,105.47Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M2319.74,3100c-1.57,0-3.15-.08-4.75-.24a46.65,46.65,0,0,1-41.72-51.12c4.2-41.51-14.39-94.68-51-145.89-34.55-48.34-82.65-90.66-125.52-110.46a46.66,46.66,0,0,1,39.14-84.72c57.55,26.59,118.22,79.27,162.29,140.92,50.35,70.42,74.47,144.84,67.92,209.54A46.68,46.68,0,0,1,2319.74,3100Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2308.5,3191.69a54.91,54.91,0,0,1-44.08-87.65,54.89,54.89,0,0,1,82.82-63.82c22.68,15.67,33.64,42.36,30.06,73.25-3.1,26.72-17.74,62.24-48.78,74.42A54.75,54.75,0,0,1,2308.5,3191.69Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M2022.92,2587.06c42.55,2.61,71.85,33.56,97.82,61.77,30.25,32.86,61.64,80.35,91.53,188.7,30.31,109.82,45.46,164.73,35.3,219.17-18.54,99.29-108.22,240.16-246.14,241.35-135,1.16-227.85-132.32-245.4-235.87-9.36-55.22,9.73-111.76,47.9-224.85,37-109.75,71.21-154,96.79-180.86C1929.58,2626.18,1970,2583.8,2022.92,2587.06Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2001.18,2616.45c31.58-.27,63.25,39.89,87.37,81.71a492.72,492.72,0,0,1,54.28,139.52c25,114.06,41.72,190.61-4.63,248.56-46.09,57.6-126.39,59.74-136.77,59.85-10.83.11-89.18-.39-134.63-57-45.26-56.38-26.74-131.75,2.7-251.54,3-12.29,29.46-79.84,73.41-161.79C1956.93,2649.61,1975.87,2616.67,2001.18,2616.45Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M865.5,1836.78c-109.3,103.92-60.91,310.4,16.55,426.94,110.37,166.07,358.19,267.53,482.6,176,129.93-95.63,107.63-388.85-48.61-538.55C1199.4,1789.37,978.54,1729.31,865.5,1836.78Z" />
    <path class="cls-5" d="M997.27,1954.6c-64.75,69.33-26.65,197.17,26.33,267.46,75.51,100.15,234.91,154.61,309.6,92.47,78-64.9,53.07-248.18-50.62-336.34C1205.16,1912.36,1064.24,1882.9,997.27,1954.6Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M3134.89,1832.12c111.1,102,66.32,309.29-9.09,427.16-107.46,168-353.47,273.75-479.45,184.37-131.58-93.35-114.4-386.92,39.19-539.32C2800.22,1790.55,3020,1726.64,3134.89,1832.12Z" />
    <path class="cls-5" d="M3005.2,1952.22c66,68.19,30.09,196.68-21.66,267.88-73.75,101.45-232.17,158.69-307.94,97.86-79.14-63.53-57.39-247.22,44.75-337.18C2796.61,1913.62,2937,1881.7,3005.2,1952.22Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M2542.19,829.7c38.86-39.54-134.68-124.74-135.25-190.15-.71-81,405.3,171.58,324.16,314.14-17.58,30.89-63.48,112.31-461.63-16.87C2667.62,1066,2967.62,1340,2966.2,1847.06c-1.09,388.75-348.57,990.75-964.93,996.12-594.62,5.19-966-596.16-964.93-996.12,1.33-488.44,432.35-989.27,966.09-1028.56C2398.25,789.36,2494.38,878.36,2542.19,829.7Z" />
    <path class="cls-6" d="M2001.27,1320.55c19.15-.16,112.39-116.75,268-116.74,223.53,0,482,324.76,482.28,643.25.16,205.85-111.65,252-111.45,275.69.19,21.13,236.88,22.58,236.88,254.71,0,209.25-420.37,512-840.86,524.16-461.31,13.34-910.31-319.74-910.31-497.74,0-232.44,237-260.58,236.85-281.27s-111.76-76.15-111.93-275.55c-.26-318.49,259.27-643.25,482.47-643.25C1905.63,1203.8,1978.54,1320.75,2001.27,1320.55Z" />
    <path class="cls-7" d="M2600.16,2330.77c32.4-4.6,56,22.77,47.08,55.45-11.75,43.09-35,85.68-67.74,125.82q-11.17,13.73-23.87,27c-115.49,121.69-320.37,213.48-554.36,213.08-234,.4-438.88-91.39-554.37-213.08q-12.66-13.29-23.86-27c-32.78-40.14-56-82.73-67.75-125.83-8.9-32.67,14.68-60,47.08-55.44A4258.57,4258.57,0,0,0,2600.16,2330.77Z" />
    <path class="cls-7" d="M2002.74,2770.57h-3c-112.73,0-225.78-21.46-327-62.09-95.65-38.4-178.38-92.6-239.24-156.73-8.78-9.21-17.13-18.66-24.79-28.07-34.94-42.79-58.91-87.41-71.23-132.62-6-21.92-1.44-43.51,12.45-59.24,13.5-15.31,33.55-22.34,55-19.29a4240,4240,0,0,0,596.3,42.15,4238.47,4238.47,0,0,0,596.3-42.15h0c21.44-3.05,41.49,4,55,19.29,13.88,15.73,18.42,37.32,12.45,59.24-12.32,45.19-36.29,89.82-71.25,132.63-7.72,9.48-16.07,18.93-24.81,28.09-60.83,64.1-143.56,118.3-239.21,156.7C2228.58,2749.11,2115.53,2770.57,2002.74,2770.57Zm-1.5-36.85h1.44c108.2,0,216.48-20.54,313.34-59.44,90.77-36.44,169-87.59,226.25-147.9,8.11-8.51,15.82-17.23,22.95-26,31.68-38.81,53.29-78.85,64.25-119,2.65-9.73,1-18.9-4.53-25.17-5.23-5.92-13.11-8.47-22.18-7.18h0a4275.86,4275.86,0,0,1-1203,0c-9.07-1.29-17,1.26-22.18,7.18-5.53,6.27-7.18,15.44-4.53,25.17,11,40.19,32.57,80.24,64.24,119,7.07,8.68,14.78,17.41,22.93,26,57.27,60.34,135.5,111.49,226.27,147.94,96.86,38.88,205.16,59.43,313.29,59.43Z" />
    <path class="cls-8" d="M2647.24,2386.21c-11.75,43.09-35,85.69-67.74,125.83q-36.18,5-72.44,9.29-6.66.81-13.33,1.58a4258.51,4258.51,0,0,1-968,1.93q-8.94-1-17.87-2.06h0q-42.43-4.94-84.78-10.74c-32.77-40.14-56-82.73-67.74-125.83-8.89-32.67,14.68-60,47.08-55.44q7.83,1.11,15.65,2.19,7.37,1,14.74,2a4258.61,4258.61,0,0,0,1153.34-2.23l10.12-1.41,3.94-.56C2632.55,2326.17,2656.14,2353.54,2647.24,2386.21Z" />
    <path class="cls-8" d="M2555.63,2539.06c-48.1,50.68-111.69,96.17-186.44,132a795,795,0,0,1-90.22,36.51c-84.24,28.31-178.35,44.76-277.7,44.59a874.36,874.36,0,0,1-243.1-33.8s0,0,0,0a814.34,814.34,0,0,1-94.37-33.52c-88-37.57-162.38-88.32-216.88-145.75q40.57,5.33,81.21,9.87c5.18.57,10.36,1.15,15.55,1.7a4258,4258,0,0,0,932.17-1.87q5.51-.62,11-1.25Q2521.27,2543.58,2555.63,2539.06Z" />
    <path class="cls-8" d="M1760,1403.06c154.89,18,266.48,208.75,250,376.77-16.39,167.34-162.7,342-329.89,323-151.79-17.3-250.26-186.22-253.5-328.16C1422.3,1584.51,1587.45,1383,1760,1403.06Z" />
    <ellipse class="cls-9" cx="1770.53" cy="1790.92" rx="210.18" ry="180.94" transform="translate(-324.93 3187.77) rotate(-79.02)" />
    <ellipse cx="1781.54" cy="1823.1" rx="105.94" ry="118.46" />
    <ellipse class="cls-8" cx="1835.31" cy="1726.3" rx="40.43" ry="42.42" transform="translate(-404.49 2880.33) rotate(-70.51)" />
    <path class="cls-8" d="M2235.68,1398.91c-154.55,20.68-262.79,213.36-243.41,381.08,19.3,167,168.63,339.1,335.47,317.13,151.47-19.94,247-190.55,247.73-332.52C2576.49,1574.44,2407.84,1375.87,2235.68,1398.91Z" />
    <ellipse class="cls-9" cx="2231.91" cy="1786.89" rx="180.94" ry="210.18" transform="translate(-322.39 502.39) rotate(-11.98)" />
    <ellipse cx="2221.47" cy="1819.26" rx="105.94" ry="118.46" transform="translate(-31.41 39.05) rotate(-1)" />
    <ellipse class="cls-8" cx="2275.94" cy="1726.33" rx="42.42" ry="40.43" transform="translate(-460.36 906.08) rotate(-20.49)" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M1785.75,2081.38c0,75.28,98.57,166.65,215.68,165.63,107.93-.94,213.18-91.24,213.18-165.41,0-59.68-124.17-112.16-213.18-111.39C1918.8,1970.93,1785.75,2010.78,1785.75,2081.38Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Second layer image:

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 4000 4000">
<defs>
    <style>.cls-1{opacity:0.05;}.cls-2{opacity:0.1;}.cls-3{opacity:0.2;}.cls-4{opacity:0.08;}</style>
</defs>
<title>shader</title>
<g id="shader">
    <path class="cls-1" d="M1850,1434.82a211.94,211.94,0,0,0-49.86-12.11c-172.54-20-337.7,181.45-333.37,371.56,2.51,110,62.25,236.26,159.68,295.51-121-45.56-197-190.72-199.85-315.16C1422.3,1584.51,1587.45,1383,1760,1403.06,1792.12,1406.79,1822.38,1418,1850,1434.82Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M2575.47,1764.59c-.67,124.47-74.15,271-194.33,318.62,96.39-61,153.92-188.21,154.5-298.27,1-190.16-167.63-388.72-339.79-365.68a212.08,212.08,0,0,0-49.68,13c27.35-17.35,57.43-29,89.5-33.34C2407.84,1375.87,2576.48,1574.44,2575.47,1764.59Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M1869.31,1609a158.22,158.22,0,0,0-18.56-4.78c-98.1-19-195.56,57.9-217.67,171.85-17.27,89,16.5,174.22,78.84,216.37-87.16-28.22-139.71-129.44-119-236,22.12-114,119.58-190.89,217.68-171.85A158.2,158.2,0,0,1,1869.31,1609Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2294.05,1987.37c61.58-43.24,93.85-129,75-217.7-24.1-113.55-122.89-188.78-220.64-168a156.86,156.86,0,0,0-18.48,5.11,158.48,158.48,0,0,1,58.3-25.46c97.76-20.75,196.54,54.48,220.65,168C2431.45,1855.52,2380.68,1957.62,2294.05,1987.37Z" />
    <path class="cls-3" d="M2214.61,2081.59c0,74.18-105.25,164.48-213.18,165.42-117.12,1-215.68-90.36-215.68-165.63a55.33,55.33,0,0,1,1.46-12.65c39.94,53.41,121.8,99,214,98.28,85.64-.67,169.74-46.83,210.9-100.17A45.83,45.83,0,0,1,2214.61,2081.59Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M1097,2439.73c-83.85-36.5-164-99.38-215-176-77.46-116.54-125.85-323-16.55-426.93,45.17-43,107.55-59.14,173.62-56q-.82,10.15-1.4,20.33c-50.28,4.26-96.49,21.49-132,55.29-109.31,103.91-60.91,310.39,16.54,426.93C964.94,2347.64,1028.26,2402.24,1097,2439.73Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M3125.8,2259.28c-49.63,77.57-128.8,141.88-212.06,179.83,68.19-38.68,130.6-94.42,172.23-159.49,75.41-117.87,120.2-325.16,9.09-427.16-35.33-32.43-80.57-48.85-129.62-52.73q-.36-10.47-.91-20.79c64.45-3.41,125.43,11.93,170.36,53.18C3246,1934.11,3201.21,2141.4,3125.8,2259.28Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2247.57,3056.69C2229,3156,2139.35,3296.86,2001.43,3298c-135,1.16-227.85-132.31-245.4-235.86a178.64,178.64,0,0,1-1.42-47.38c.3,2.46.65,4.92,1.07,7.38,17.55,103.55,110.38,237,245.4,235.86,137.92-1.18,227.6-142.05,246.14-241.34,1.07-5.76,1.87-11.52,2.38-17.35C2251.54,3019.91,2251,3038.33,2247.57,3056.69Z" />
    <g class="cls-3">
        <path d="M2267.51,3173.33c-11.06,5.09-30.83,7.25-66-2.54q3.45-5.48,6.65-11c24.86,7.24,42.33,8.69,54.58,7.3A52.66,52.66,0,0,0,2267.51,3173.33Z" />
        <path d="M2566.83,3042.84a38.52,38.52,0,0,0,9.66-5.13,41.64,41.64,0,0,1-19.57,15.22c-29.25,10.51-62.64-17.51-63-17.8a18.94,18.94,0,0,0-19.87-2.93,19.13,19.13,0,0,1,3.08-5,18.94,18.94,0,0,1,26.7-2.14C2504.19,3025.33,2537.58,3053.35,2566.83,3042.84Z" />
        <path d="M2632.39,3018.8c-6,19.09-16,34.68-28.85,45.72a105.14,105.14,0,0,0,18.94-35.63c7.32-23.08,8.67-50.8,3.61-74.15-6.17-28.49-22.66-54.2-47.68-74.34-21.8-17.55-48.41-29.47-74.94-33.58-41.18-6.37-84.4,5.86-125,35.36a247,247,0,0,0-26.12,22,250.49,250.49,0,0,1,36-32.06c40.59-29.5,83.81-41.72,125-35.36,26.53,4.11,53.14,16,74.94,33.58,25,20.14,41.51,45.85,47.69,74.34C2641.06,2968,2639.71,2995.72,2632.39,3018.8Z" />
    </g>
    <path class="cls-1" d="M1360.7,2126.07c11.9-10.67-113.73-80.72-109.94-279,.11-5.45.07-10.91.22-16.37,8.5,180.23,141.67,258.15,141.84,277.92C1392.85,2112.33,1373.28,2120.71,1360.7,2126.07Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M2610.35,2101.65c-.2-23.12,135.56-86.47,140.69-279.55.35,8.32.14,16.65.54,25,9.56,197.82-123.27,264.93-110.31,278.16C2627.73,2121,2610.39,2105.61,2610.35,2101.65Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M2877,2377.46c0,209.25-420.37,512-840.86,524.16-461.31,13.34-910.31-319.75-910.31-497.75q0-12.16.85-23.59c25.71,181.25,461.62,494.28,909.11,481.34,410.88-11.88,821.64-301.22,840.2-509.67Q2877,2364.22,2877,2377.46Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M1730.65,3184.68a54.77,54.77,0,0,1-51.13,6.84c-16.08-6-29-18.39-38.52-36.88a116,116,0,0,1-11.55-36.67c-2.74-20.52,1-39.29,10.41-54.29-.07-.45-.14-.89-.19-1.35-7.55-63.51,14.39-136.94,61.84-207.16q9.77,2.91,19.62,5.67c-40.3,65.3-59.68,119-52.7,177.78,0,.46-.06-.45,0,0-9.41,15-11.81,48.57-9.07,69.09a116.08,116.08,0,0,0,11.55,36.67c9.48,18.49,22.44,30.9,38.52,36.88a54.69,54.69,0,0,0,19.13,3.46C1729.26,3184.72,1730,3184.71,1730.65,3184.68Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M2377.29,3113.47c-3.09,26.72-17.73,62.24-48.78,74.41a54.79,54.79,0,0,1-51.25-6c.38,0,.77,0,1.15,0a55,55,0,0,0,20-3.8c31.05-12.18,45.68-47.7,48.78-74.42,2.38-20.56-.59-54.27-10.26-69.11.06-.44,0,.46,0,0,5.81-57.38-13.43-108.74-52.78-171.85q10-2.79,20-5.76c46.28,67.88,68.24,138.92,62,201-.05.46-.11.9-.17,1.35C2375.61,3074.2,2379.68,3092.91,2377.29,3113.47Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M1985.53,3389.64a54.89,54.89,0,0,1-69.38,34.82c-26.37-8.75-93.26-15.62-132.68,1.84a54.92,54.92,0,0,1-77-46.67,54.85,54.85,0,0,0,71.84,26.72c39.42-17.46,106.32-10.6,132.69-1.85a54.9,54.9,0,0,0,72.06-55.64A54.7,54.7,0,0,1,1985.53,3389.64Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M2298.58,3378a54.86,54.86,0,0,1-76.19,48c-39.72-16.76-106.49-8.73-132.71.47a54.89,54.89,0,0,1-68.2-74.4,54.91,54.91,0,0,0,73,54.36c26.22-9.21,93-17.24,132.7-.47a54.83,54.83,0,0,0,71.37-28Z" />
    <path class="cls-4" d="M2138.19,3086.24c-46.08,57.6-126.38,59.74-136.76,59.84-10.83.12-89.18-.38-134.63-57-21.19-26.39-28.4-57-27.06-94.28,1.63,28.47,9.6,52.76,26.88,74.28,45.46,56.63,123.81,57.13,134.63,57,10.38-.11,90.69-2.25,136.77-59.85,19.78-24.72,28.06-52.83,29.13-85.79C2169.07,3022.24,2161.85,3056.66,2138.19,3086.24Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2750.8,1816.91c-15.74-308.51-265-613.11-481.5-613.11-155.64,0-248.88,116.58-268,116.75-22.73.2-95.64-116.75-268-116.75-218.18,0-471.06,310.31-482.1,621.74q-.78-13.72-.81-28.48c-.26-318.49,259.27-643.25,482.47-643.26,172.41,0,245.31,117,268,116.75,19.15-.17,112.39-116.75,268-116.75,223.52,0,482,324.77,482.27,643.26Q2751.16,1807.25,2750.8,1816.91Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2473.67,674.35c-.15-17.72,8.93-28.23,62.15-5.43-69.23-42.34-129.15-60.54-128.88-29.37.57,65.4,174.11,150.61,135.25,190.15-47.82,48.66-143.94-40.34-539.76-11.2-533.75,39.29-964.77,540.12-966.09,1028.56-.35,129.83,38.54,280.85,111.58,425.48v0l1.29,2.52q1.86,3.66,3.74,7.3c.87-1.71,1.76-3.39,2.66-5.06l.66-1.21q2.73-5,5.66-9.77l.66-1.08q1.44-2.33,2.93-4.61l0-.08c1-1.56,2-3.09,3.1-4.61l.69-1q1.5-2.16,3-4.26l.15-.21q1.6-2.19,3.25-4.33c.25-.33.5-.66.76-1q1.5-1.95,3-3.85l.31-.39q1.65-2,3.33-4l.9-1q1.44-1.68,2.89-3.31l.61-.69c70.21-78.43,175.19-95.5,175.07-109.27,0-3.27-2.87-7.43-7.63-12.9-25.54,13.92-113.62,31-172.71,99.27-46.31-115.84-85.59-250.75-85.31-351.82,1.33-488.44,452-960.07,985.73-999.36,395.82-29.14,491.95,59.86,539.77,11.2C2661.39,829.46,2474.24,739.75,2473.67,674.35Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2966.2,1847.06c1.35-482.72-270.46-754.2-640.08-890.61-86.12-31.59-74.29-16.76-109.17-28.08,398.15,129.18,710.58,402,709.16,909-.32,115-27.37,241.26-86.32,372.62-57.8-80.49-163.52-88.39-192.17-100.84-4.72,5.46-7.52,9.79-7.49,13.56.13,15.13,121.52,20.18,190.45,107h0q5.36,6.73,10.25,14.14l0,0c1.08,1.63,2.13,3.28,3.17,5l0,.08c1,1.68,2.05,3.38,3,5.1a.41.41,0,0,1,.05.09q1.5,2.6,2.93,5.26l0,.07c1,1.79,1.89,3.6,2.81,5.45l0,0q1.38,2.77,2.7,5.64c1.5-3,3-6.05,4.48-9.09h0C2929.62,2119.3,2965.85,1972.14,2966.2,1847.06Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M1949.22,3291.58c-.57,4.42-1.08,8.93-1.52,13.56-50.19-13.56-92.55-45.85-124.81-85.56q1.26-5.46,2.59-10.73C1857.73,3247.49,1899.7,3278.64,1949.22,3291.58Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2178.62,3217.15h0c-31.79,39.62-73.27,72.47-123,86.94q-.84-6.9-1.87-13.49c49.09-13.81,90.24-45.54,122-84.13Q2177.25,3211.71,2178.62,3217.15Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2194,3308c-52.67-5-105.6,3.5-136.57,13.54q-.4-4.95-.91-9.74c30.69-10.1,83.68-18.74,136.52-13.88Q2193.55,3302.92,2194,3308Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M1947.33,3309.2c-.28,3.2-.52,6.45-.74,9.75-31.15-9.5-84.22-17.07-136.78-11.17.23-3.4.49-6.77.78-10.09C1863.34,3291.92,1916.47,3299.63,1947.33,3309.2Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M1512.69,2523.35l-4.87-.57h0q-42.43-4.94-84.78-10.74c-32.77-40.15-56-82.73-67.74-125.83-8.9-32.68,14.68-60.05,47.08-55.44,5.22.73,10.43,1.47,15.65,2.19l2.44.33C1439.87,2399.23,1469.68,2463.73,1512.69,2523.35Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M1740.15,2712.92a810.14,810.14,0,0,1-76.37-28.11c-88-37.57-162.38-88.33-216.88-145.75q40.57,5.33,81.21,9.86l1.48.16C1582.24,2611.78,1651.21,2667.87,1740.15,2712.92Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M2647.24,2386.21c-11.75,43.09-35,85.68-67.74,125.83q-36.18,5-72.45,9.29l-11.58,1.37c41.19-59.77,69.41-124,87.46-189.53l3.16-.43,10.13-1.42,3.94-.55C2632.55,2326.16,2656.14,2353.53,2647.24,2386.21Z" />
    <path class="cls-1" d="M2555.63,2539.06c-48.1,50.68-111.69,96.17-186.44,132a790.65,790.65,0,0,1-74.71,31.12c75.86-43.85,135.64-96,182.09-153.34l1.48-.19,7.14-.93,1.67-.19Q2521.26,2543.58,2555.63,2539.06Z" />
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2304.15,2857q-39.86,11.91-80.78,20.95-8.65,1.92-17.35,3.68-25.77,5.23-51.81,9.2a972.49,972.49,0,0,1-118.06,10.79,1000.28,1000.28,0,0,1-179.37-11.42q-29-4.41-57.48-10.33c-3-.62-6-1.26-9-1.9q-45.07-9.72-88.76-22.8-8.44,12.48-15.79,25.09c30.82,9.66,62.31,18.19,94.3,25.39l.74-1.09,1.46-2.1c-.38,1.15-.75,2.3-1.11,3.43q34.26,7.68,69.24,13.27a1002.45,1002.45,0,0,0,186.06,12.46A975.24,975.24,0,0,0,2159.79,2920q33.12-5.21,65.84-12.5c1.77-.39,3.54-.78,5.3-1.19q45.21-10.26,89.19-24.13Q2312.7,2869.55,2304.15,2857Z" />
</g>
<g id="outline_shader" data-name="outline+shader">
    <path class="cls-2" d="M2214.79,2101.6c0,74.18-105.25,164.48-213.18,165.42-117.12,1-215.68-90.36-215.68-165.63q0-1.65.09-3.27c0-.3.06-.59.08-.89.06-.78.12-1.55.21-2.32,0-.35.1-.69.15-1s0-.41.08-.62c9.52,72.67,103.87,154.73,214.89,153.76,102.62-.89,202.81-82.57,212.43-154.36,0,.13,0,.26.08.39s0,.28.07.41a44.2,44.2,0,0,1,.66,5.1l0,.5C2214.75,2099.9,2214.79,2100.75,2214.79,2101.6Z" />
</g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuing from the suggestion of the previous answer.I didn't find an already made Python solution that rewrites the class name in the elements and the class attribute of each path so I have created one myself:

https://github.com/Amirh24/SVGAppender

Feel free to use it :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import svgutils.transform as st

template = st.fromfile('firstLayer.svg')
second_svg = st.fromfile('secondLayer.svg')
template.append(second_svg)
template.save('merged.svg')
```

This is a solution from [another post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23139709/svgwrite-how-to-enable-write-add-other-objects-as-layers-of-an-existing-svg-f).

The catch is that you will need to choose different class names for each file, or the styles from each file will interfere with each other. For example `cls-1` class from the first document will also have applied to it `opacity:0.05` from the second document.

`secondLayer.svg` will be the file that you append, because appending it will mean its further down the document, which for SVG means it will be on top.

Comment: The results comes out super weird. Aren't the <defs><style> important? they are gone in the second layer

Comment: Yeah I checked it and if I change the cls names it turns out fine. I do have a lot of pictures to stack on each other. Do you know if there is a dynamic solution? Some sort of library that dynamically changes the classes names with respect to the number of classes that already exists in the SVG? Thanks

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872978/search-and-alter-text-with-python-in-a-svg-file)  post may prove helpful for doing all of that dynamically. I'll try to come up with another solution soon.

Comment: Great, thank you!. If no solution like that exists i'm just going to make it and open source it. Will post the results in here.